# Is response.ok true for any 2xx HTTP status?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Is `response.ok` true for any 2xx HTTP status? If so, why? Shouldn't it be only for a 200 status code?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok — Any 2xx is generally a successful response: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fetch specs state, that a response [returns true](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-response-ok) if the response status has an [OK status](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ok-status).

> An ok status is a status in the range 200 to 299, inclusive.

The reason for this seems to, that a 2xx status yields a successfull response, which is pretty common for 201, 206 etc. in the RESTful world.